# How to safely update hive external table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have an external hive table and I would like to refresh the data files on a daily basis. What is the recommended way to do this?

If I just overwrite the files, and if we are unlucky enough to have some other hive queries to execute in parallel against this table, what will happen to those queries? Will they just fail? Or will my HDFS operations fail? Or will they block until the queries complete?

Comment: Do you have ACID transactions enabled?

Comment: No, but I think I can change that if needed.

Comment: I don't think Hive can lock the HDFS files. And you're definitely able to delete them with the proper permissions at any point. I think the query results will come back with missing data but not error, though, just the map attempts will maybe silently fail in the background

Answer (score 0):

If availability is a concern and space isn't an issue, you can do the following:

1. Make a synonym for the external table.  Make sure all queries use this synonym when accessing the table.
2. When loading new data, load it to a new table with a different name.
3. When the load is complete, point the synonym to the newly loaded table.
4. After an appropriate length of time (long enough for any running queries to finish), drop the previous table.

Comment: Can you provide example HQL statements or point to documentation? The only reference to synonym tables I can find is [this open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7088) which would indicate that no such feature exists yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all.. if you are accessing any table it may have two types of locks:

exclusive(if data is getting added) and shared(if data is getting read)..

so if you insert overwrite and add data into the table then at that time if you access the table with other queries, they wont get executed because there will be an exclusive lock on it and once the insert overwrite query completes then you may access the table.

Please refer to the following link:

```
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking
```